# Why is my simply python calculator giving 2 answers (1 correct, 1 wrong) when dividing?

Tags: python, calculator

Doing this for school and I decided to make a calculator. This code works fine except dividing gives me 2 answers?

**EDIT: Seemed to be subtracting once I added the option to also be able to input "sub". I removed that option and it fixed it.**

```
#Numbers/Answer to Add
print("If your not Adam, welcome to The Calculator\n")
firstNumb = float(input("A number\n"))
secondNumb = float(input("Another number\n"))
operation = input("mutliply/divide/subtract/add?\n")

#Operating

answerMult = firstNumb * secondNumb
answerDiv = firstNumb / secondNumb
answerAdd = firstNumb + secondNumb
answerSub = firstNumb - secondNumb

#Printing answers

if(operation == "multiply"):
    print(answerMult)

if(operation == "divide"):
    print(answerDiv)

if(operation == "add"):
    print(answerAdd)

if(operation == "subtract","sub"):
    print(answerSub)


#EasterEgg

if((answerAdd) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerSub) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerMult) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerDiv) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just fixed it. Seems that the option to input "sub" was screwing with the rest for some reason. I removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Yup, I glossed straight over the `operation == "subtract","sub"` test you have there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on these lines:

```
if(operation == "subtract","sub"):
    print(answerSub)
```

The `(operation == "subtract, "sub")` creates a tuple, like `(False, "sub")`, and that's always `True`.

You're confused about `==` behavior, you can just use `if operation in ["subtract", "sub"]:`

A small suggestion, on Python, the parentheses around if statement conditions are unnecessary and likely to lead to some bugs. You can just omit the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your divide:

```
if(operation == "subtract","sub"):
```

This should be

```
if (operation == "subtract") or (operation == "sub"):
```

or

```
if operation in ["subtract", "sub"]:
```

Comment: I just figured out that was the problem but didnt know how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is what utdemir said. removing the "sub" part gives the correct solution

```
print("If your not Adam, welcome to The Calculator\n")
firstNumb = float(input("A number\n"))
secondNumb = float(input("Another number\n"))
operation = input("mutliply/divide/subtract/add?\n")

#Operating

answerMult = firstNumb * secondNumb
answerDiv = firstNumb / secondNumb
answerAdd = firstNumb + secondNumb
answerSub = firstNumb - secondNumb

#Printing answers

if(operation == "multiply"):
    print(answerMult)

if(operation == "divide"):
    print(answerDiv)

if(operation == "add"):
    print(answerAdd)

if(operation == "subtract"):
    print(answerSub)


#EasterEgg

if((answerAdd) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerSub) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerMult) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")

if((answerDiv) == 9001):
    while(1==1):print("ITS OVAR 9000!!!!!!\n")
```